# Is there a way with PHP to access a file on a server and save only the first half of the file?

Tags: php, javascript, web-services

I want to give users a preview of certain files on my site and will be using scribd API. Does anyone know how I can access the full file from my server and save the file under a different name , which I will then show to users..Can't think of a way to do this with PHP for .docx and image files...Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Showing *half an image*? How would that work? For Word documents, you'll need to specifically *parse* the file; if you just hack it in half, it'll corrupt. Overall, you'll need to custom-process every type of file individually.

Comment: Basically I would save the file in half, so that a user can only see half..yes, even images because the images would be text based..Please expound on how to custom process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For "splitting" images, use an image processing library like [gd](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) to *crop* the image (lots of examples to be found on how to do that all over the place). For Word documents, use a library like [PHPWord](http://phpword.codeplex.com/) (or one of the other myriad such libraries) to open the document, remove/extract as much text as you need, then save that into a new Word file.

For other file types, find the appropriate method that allows you to *manipulate* that format, then do whatever you need to do with it.